# Нагрузочное тестирование rest api Jmeter

Tags: юнит-тесты, rest, нагрузочное-тестирование, jmeter

Можно ли и если можно то как с помощью `Jmeter` симулировать работу клиентов с `API` на разных устройствах. Вернеее устройств имеющих разные ip?

Например я запускаю тест для 50 пользователей по сценарию : `1:логирование` - `2:запрос личных данных` - `3:отправка сообщения другому пользователю`.

`REST API` сервис устроен так, что залогинится с одного IP нельзя пока не завершится текущая сессия. В связи с этим вопрос продвинутым тестировщикам - можно ли научить `Jmeter` (или любой другой инструмент) тестировать API через прокси сервера динамически?

Answer (score 1):

Можно

1. Есть такое понятие как [IP Spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter), каждому виртуальному пользователю можно указать уникальный IP адрес

   [image: JMeter IP Spoofing]
2. Можно направить запросы через прокси сервер, конфигурация находится там же (на закладке "Advanced" элемента [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request))

   [image: JMeter Proxy for request]

   но в этом случае вы должны быть уверены что прокси сервер достаточно быстр и не станет [узким местом](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)

Comment: Первый вариант привел меня к ошибке `invalid IPv6 address at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName`. Второй с добавлением реального прокси - работает, хоть и значительно медленне. Есть ли возможность автоматизировать процесс не указывая каждый раз новый прокси ?

Comment: Со вторым вариантом разобрался а первый все еще падает с ошибкой.